# What is the cheapest way of travelling between London and Paris by public transportation?

Tags: trains, public-transport, buses, london, paris

I am looking for the cheapest way to travel between London and Paris, by public transportation.
I'm planning a 2-month trip to Paris for this summer. I wonder how to get from London to Paris spending as little money as possible. I am open to taking trains, buses or any other cheapest way of travelling because a plane ticket will be very costly for me.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/79682/discussion-on-question-by-tashi-jutt-what-is-the-cheapest-way-of-travelling-betw).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to go **Paris cheaply** and are in no hurry then using the coach/bus services may be your preferred solution.

**Flixbus, OUIBUS and Eurolines** are three major bus lines traveling between London and Paris. Info below is taken from [www.european-traveler.com](https://www.european-traveler.com/france/cheap-buses-london-paris/)

**1. Flixbus Coaches:**

> **Flixbus**, Europe’s largest intercity bus operator, has taken over all Megabus service on continental Europe and is usually the cheapest for bus travel between Paris and London. Ticket prices generally range from **£20 to £50** but deals of around **€15** are often easy to find.

**2. Ouibus Coaches:**

> **Ouibus** has up to **eight coaches per day** traveling in each direction between Paris and London. The lowest one-way fares on Ouibus are around **€30**, which is slightly higher than on Flixbus.

**3. Eurolines Buses / National Express:**

> **National Express / Eurolines Buses**, which has a much larger network of intercity buses in the UK, have around **seven coach services daily** between Paris and London. One-way fares from London to Paris on National Express / Eurolines buses are from **€20 to €40**. Discounts are available for return journeys booked online – returns for around **£50** are fairly easy to find.

Comment: This answer has been wholly copied from other websites. [Plagiarism](https://travel.stackexchange.com/help/referencing) is [not cool](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/83955/plagiarism-should-be-addressed-specifically-in-the-faq/134715#134715). It's not a bad answer, but it's not *your* answer, so don't pretend you wrote it.

Comment: It's a platform for solving problems. If someone has any problem then you can answer him/her and try to solve the problem. I already mention the source of the content. I never said that this is my content.

Comment: When I posted this comment, your answer did not cite its where you had copied the content from, and you claimed to have written it all on your own (since it has your name at the bottom, and no other attribution). Now your answer is *still* not citing the other site you copied from, and still not marking the cited content as being a quote. You were dishonest, and you're still dishonest.

Comment: I think you didn't see the link on the top of my answer. You just blaming me without seeing the complete answer. I am not dishonest.

Comment: @MuhammadTahseenurRehman you are aware, I hope, that this whole site is a wiki?  We can see when you edited that link into your article (2 hours ago, at the time of writing) and when Gilles posted his first comment (3 hours ago, at the time of writing).  It's obvious to everyone that when Gilles posted his first comment you had not, in fact, put that link at the top of your article.  Coming over all injured and offended just makes you look rather unimpressive.

Answer (score 49):

If you are not time sensitive, then [Eurostar Snap](https://snap.eurostar.com/uk-en/home) is an option. You pick a day and either morning or afternoon and then get told the train time the day before. (It lets them fill empty seats.)

There are seats at £25 within the next couple of weeks, and that leaves you in central London/Paris.

Comment: It may be worth pointed out that using Eurostar Snap is only possible for people who have a Twitter or Facebook account.

Comment: @a3nm that's weird and silly.